# PDO Insert doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This day is my first time using PDO. And when I try 'INSERT' with PDO, it does nothing.

This is my code :

```
session_start();
if($_GET['feedback']!="")
{
    $fb = $_GET['feedback'];

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $query = "INSERT INTO feedback(number, sender, content, date) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['alias']);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $fb);
    $STH->bindParam(3, $date);
    $STH->execute();
}
```

I have tried  a 'SELECT' query with PDO and it works.
What should I do?

Comment: can you check your mysql log?

Comment: i don't know, how to do that? I have try $STH->errorInfo() it show 'Array'.

Comment: Ypu need to connect first. check [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)  for the example. You need also turn on error_displaying and reporting

Comment: Why you no use execute() method?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i already connect it :) i have try with 'SELECT' query for other case and its work. How to turn on error_displaying and reporting?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php - use `print_r($STH->errorInfo())`

Comment: Are you sure `bindParam()` is right?  Don't you want `bindValue()`?

Comment: @Sean i put it before execute(), it show 'Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) 1', i put it after execute(), it show nothing.

Comment: @leftclickben I have tried both of them. It still same :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try and enclose your code in try and catch blocks to get any exceptions:

```
    try {

           //your code

    } catch( PDOEXception $e ) {


           echo $e->getMessage(); // display error
           exit();


    }
```

This should give you a clue whats going wrong.

Comment: well according to the php example in the php manual you can use echo. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do?

**Error reporting.**
Check [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for the example.

> It is essential to set ERRMODE_EXCEPTION as a connection option as it
>   will let PDO throw exceptions on connection errors. Setting
>   ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE is also a good idea.
>
> Please note that connection errors shouldn't be catched, at least not
>   using try..catch operator. A custom exception handler could be used,
>   but not required. Especially for new users, it is okay to have
>   unhandled exceptions, as they are extremely informative and helpful.